# where do I apply logic code for user registration in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using custom registration in Laravel.
In register.blade.php the user gives the following data

`$data['User_name','User_Coll_name','Branch_name','email','password']`

And I want to create new user with Class_id

```
 $class= DB::select('select * from classes where College_id = ? And Branchc_id = ? ',[$data['User_Coll_name'],$data['Branch_name']]);
```

I'm new to laravel please help me, where do I apply above logic. And also how to create new class if doesn't exist

```
$class = new class();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing this.

1) In `App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`, there is a `create` method. You can add your logic to create a new class and associate it with the user in this method.

2) My favorite way of doing it is by using [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events) & Listeners. So each time somebody has registered, you can fire the event and then through the listener, you do the appropriate logic.